# How to overcome the error "Operations error" in ldap_search() function in php

Tags: php

I need to retrieve data from my Active Directory where Sirname starts with 'S'.
I am getting the error in the `LDAP_Search()` function which is as below
"ldap_search(): Search: Operations error"

I have added the below lines to the code as well. But still the error occurs.
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); 
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

```
echo "<h3>LDAP query test</h3>";
echo "Connecting ...";
$ds=ldap_connect("XXXXXXXXX");  // must be a valid LDAP server!
echo "connect result is " . $ds . "<br />";
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); 
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if ($ds) { 
    echo "Binding ..."; 
    $r=ldap_bind($ds);     // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically
                           // read-only access
    echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

    echo "Searching for (sn=S*) ...";
    // Search surname entry
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "o=IT*, co=SL", "sn=S*");  
    echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

    echo "Number of entires returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

    echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
        echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
        echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
        echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
    }

    echo "Closing connection";
    ldap_close($ds);
} 
else {
    echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
```

Actual Result: It should return all the surnames starting with 'S'

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with PHP LDAP or AD, but I'm suspicious of the asterisk in your root DN - if that's a literal asterisk then it should be escaped. If not then I'm confused as to why you wouldn't know your root DN.

I also wonder if there's more error info you can get at - in my LDAP experience there has been additionalText available which gives more info on what happened beyond "operations error".
Operations Error covers quite a lot of potential scenarios so it'd be good to narrow it down a bit - if other searches work then it could well be your query, if they don't then it might be an issue with the bind or the server.
It looks like you're doing an anonymous bind - are anonymous searches allowed too?